# semi-supervised classification with a single label

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, semi-supervised-learning

I have a dataset of 1800 entries with about 40 features (some binary, some numerical). Of the 1800, 12 are known to be good for my goal; and the rest are unknown. Of the 1800 only 25-30 of the entries are expected to be good; so this is an unbalanced dataset. I am trying to find the other promising candidates that are similar to these 12. Is it possible to classify (or cluster) this dataset in an unsupervised manner with the seeds?

Comment: 0. Welcome to SE.CV. 1. Can you please define a bit more what you mean by "are expected to be good"? Is this referring to some qualitative property? Is it simply a class label? Something else? 2. The obvious thing is to define a metric of similarity, and start examining the rest of the 1788 entries based on how similar they are to the known 12 good entries. But that is not "classification" but rather exploration. 3. Assuming you can define a metric space exploring point within the convex hull of that space that also are similar to the known 12 points might be more fruitful too.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I have 12 molecules that can successfully interact with a biochemical compound in a lab setting. A molecule that interacts with the compound is "good", and one that does not is "not good". Labels are binary. I also have ~1800 more leads that might or might not interact with the compound. Each test takes about a month; so I am trying to find a shortcut to decrease the number of candidates. I dont really have a metric and the feature space is very large and non-linear. What I am trying to find out is if I can pre-seed an unsupervised classifier and have it suggest a relationship

Comment: I do understand that this is not necessarily a classification operation; and I also understand that it might not be feasible. But unfortunately I am new to ML and dont know enough yet. I was hoping for some suggestions on how to proceeed. thank you for the interest.